# Regular Expression to parse some special cases of C Code

Tags: regex

I am trying to check generated C Code with a regular expression.

Actually the lines I need to check always start the same way

```
R_Wrt_somename(V_var)
```

or

```
R_Wrt_othername((int64) (V_var2 * 3))
```

I already got an expression for the first one, but I am not able to get a fitting expression for the second possibility of function call.

Is there someone able to help me out with this problem? I also would appreciate a regular expression with explanation as I just started working with them.

The expression for the first function type:

```
R_Wrt_(\w+)\((\s*(V_)[a-zA-Z_0-9\[\] ]+)
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Using a regex for parsing general C is essentially a losing proposition.  Even for restricted subsets, it can be a challenge.  Which parts of your examples vary, and which parts are fixed?  It appears that the prefix of `R_Wrt_` might be fixed; the rest of the name up to the parenthesis is variable.  Can there be blanks before?  Before the parenthesis?  Is the `V_` prefix to the simple variable reference fixed, or can that vary?  What have you written for the first match?  Which language are you embedding your regex in?  How much does the second example vary?

Comment: For example, is it always `(int64)` as the cast, or can it be other types?  Is the expression after the cast always parenthesized?  Is it always a single set of parentheses, with a single variable and a multiplication; is the number always 3?  Can the expression be more complex than that?  What problems are you looking for?  Is there a semicolon after these expressions, or more material?  As you can see, you've left an awful lot of information out of the question — and it is hard to give a good answer until we know what you're dealing with.

Comment: You stated that you already have a regex for the first pattern, could you add it to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex that should fetch you expected results:

```
R_Wrt_(\w+)\((?:\((\w+)\)\s*)?\(?(\s*(V_)[a-zA-Z_0-9\[\]* ]+)\)*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO7tC8/1)

The regex matches:

- `R_Wrt_` - literal `R_Wrt`
- `(\w+)` - 1 or more English letters, digits or underscore (captured into Group 1)
- `\(` - a literal opening parenthesis
- `(?:\((\w+)\)\s*)?` - an optional non-capturing group (so as not to mess the groups) that matches...

  - `\(` - a literal opening parenthesis
  - `(\w+)` - 1 or more English letters, digits or underscore (captured into Group 2)
  - `\)\s*` - a literal closing parenthesis with optional whitespace
- `\(?` - a literal optional opening parenthesis
- `(\s*(V_)[a-zA-Z_0-9\[\]* ]+)` - a capturing group 3 (from your original regex) matching...

  - `\s*` - optional whitespace
  - `(V_)` - literal `V_` (captured into Group 4)
  - `[a-zA-Z_0-9\[\]* ]+` - 1 or more characters from the set
- `\)*` - 0 or more literal closing parentheses.